# Why is Java skipping an if clause if they contain similar comparisons?

Tags: java, if-statement, contains

So, I just started to get my hands dirty on Java this week and I found something rather odd. I'll add the code and then walk you through.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class kids
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("How old are you, doll?");
        
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int age = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Doggie lover or a cat person?");
        String animal = scanner.nextLine();
        
        if(age < 18 && animal.contains("dog")) // 1st comparison
        {
            System.out.println("Hello cutie, welcome");
        }
        else if(age < 18 && animal.contains("cat")) // 2nd comparison
        {
            System.out.println("Oh, hi"); // This statement gets skipped
        }
        else if(age < 18 && animal.contains("cat")); // 3rd comparison
        {
            System.out.println("Hiya, Doggie lover!");
        }
    }
}
```

I've attached my output here
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ajvu2.png)

So, I gave an input **"dogcat"** to the string animal. It is pretty clear or at least to me that the three comparisons should return TRUE but my output says otherwise. Seems like only the first and the third comparisons return TRUE but clearly if the third comparison returns TRUE since it contains the string "cat" so does the second comparison. Why is Java skipping my comparison here?

Comment: Do not use `else if` but multiple `if`s if you want all the ifs to conditionally do something one after the other. `else if`s will execute only the first block that evaluates to true.

Comment: Java is skipping your comparison because you _told it to_ by writing the `else` in this chain.

Comment: okay but why does the third one runs tho? :\

Comment: The third one runs because of the typo in your code where you put a `;` after the `if` condition.  (Spoiler: `System.out.println("Hiya, Doggie lover!");` will run in your current version of the code _no matter what_ `animal` is.)  Using an autoformatter will make bugs like this obvious.

Comment: @LouisWasserman didn't notice that, good eye

Comment: You're smart @LouisWasserman, I'm following you! Also, Why does it not throw an error?

Comment: Why would it throw an error?  It's syntactically valid, it's just buggy.

Comment: Post text instead of images here, whenever possible.

Comment: @BasilBourque, sure, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For input dogcat, it only executes the first if condition. Since other two conditions are given as else if conditions, they do not get executed.

Confusion happens because of the typo of having an semicolon just after the 3rd if condition. So the typo makes an empty statement for 3rd if condition.

The statements in the last set of curly braces are not a part of 3rd if condition due to the typo.

Comment: I think I get it now; Since the third one came off as an empty statement that makes the following sysout print all the time?

Comment: Yes, correct. Due to typo, last sysout is just an statement without any conditional check.

Comment: When you have only a single statement for an if condition, it is not mandatory to use curly braces. Here, your single statement for 3rd if is just a ;

Comment: That was really helpful, so clear!